# How to fix static method error while making Eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables `queries` and `query_feedback_types`, the query table has one foreign key as `query_feedback_type_id`, I have created two models for respective tables as `Query.php` and `QueryFeedbackType.php` these are both inside my `App\Admin` folder.

So my problem is that when I try to make an Eloquent relationship between these two tables and returning all data from Queries table with the help of model Query and then I want to have data of query_feedback_types table also, but I am unable to access it via `$row->queryFeedbackType->query`, this is giving me an error as

> "Cannot make static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::query()
>   non static in class App\Admin\QueryFeedbackType"

I have already created a similar relationship but the table name in the database was very simple for it , faqs and categories with the foreign key in faqs as category_id.

and that relationship worked perfectly

Model Query.php

```
namespace App\Admin;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Query extends Model
{
  public function queryFeedbackType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Admin\QueryFeedbackType');
}

protected $fillable= 
['name','email_id','mobile_no','query_feedback_type_id','remark'];
}
```

Model QueryFeedbackType

```
<?php

namespace App\Admin;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class QueryFeedbackType extends Model
{
    public function query()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Admin\Query');
}
}
```

Controller QueryController.php

```
use DB;
use validator;
use File;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Resize_Image;
use Helper;

class QueryController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $data['page'] = 'View Feedback/Query';
    $data['template'] = 'admin/query/view';
    $data['results'] = Query::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    return view('admin/includes/page', compact('data'));
}
}
```

my coding page

```
<?php if ($data['results']){
          $i=1;
          foreach ($data['results'] as $row) {
            ?>

            <tr>
              {{$row->query_feedback_type}}
              <td><center><?php echo $row->name; ?></center></td>

              <td><center><?php echo $row->queryFeedbackType->id ?> //getting error in this line
```

**Error:**

> "Cannot make static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::query() non 
>       static in class App\Admin\QueryFeedbackType"

Please explain to me the mistake I am doing here.

Comment: It seems clear from the error message that the `Model` class you're extending has indicated that the `query` function is static, but your implementations don't have it as static.

Comment: Sir is this error is due to following wrong naming convention in laravel tables and foreign id??

i have done exactly the same thing in two other table but that worked, but their name was simple with no underscore in table names, please tell me that, my table ```query_feedback_tables is making some problem here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model is extending `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` which already contains a static query function :

```
/**
* Begin querying the model.
*
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
*/
public static function query()
{
    return (new static)->newQuery();
}
```

Fo every eloquent query under the hood, ORM will try to call this query method statically even if you don't do it. It happens internally to instantiate the query builder for your model. As in your model, you are having a method with same name `query` which is a non-static method. This is the reason why you are getting this error.

I think in your case `query()` function is nothing but a simple relation. I would suggest to rename it to something like `queries` as it's hasMany. It will also help you remove the overlapping of function name to default static function `query`.

Comment: thank you so much sir, u cleared my confusion, now i understood that i was using one of the default function name query() so that was my mistake, now i have changed the name of the function as queryTable() and the relationship now working superb fine, thankssssss....... :)

Answer (score 0):

A static method by name query already exists in Model class that you have extended and in you'r class you are making non static method with same name that's why ur getting error change the name of the method.