# creating a new user in laravel takes a really long time

Tags: php, laravel

I am a laravel noob who has inherited an application.

I am debugging some create user code

This is the code block in question

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
$model = static::query()->create($attributes);
$logdata = DB::getQueryLog();
Log::info("(".__LINE__.") ".__FILE__." -->".__METHOD__." =". print_r($logdata, true)."\n");
```

when i look at the results at $logdata

I see 10680 entries in this array like the one below where index 0 is different for each one

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [query] => select exists(select * from `users` where `varSlug` = ? and `id` != ?) as `exists`
            [bindings] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [time] => 41.34
        )
```

So if i am reading this correctly , it is doing all these queries before the insert????

This can not be correct?

No wonder it takes forever..

I must be doing something wrong?

Would love some insight / help

A really long time is 60-120 seconds.

Attributes looks like

> ```
>     $attributes = [
>         'name' => 'Guest '.$milliseconds,
>         'email' => "g_$milliseconds@my.com",
>         'phone' => "5555555555",
>         'birthday' => "01010000",
>         'my_role' => 3,
>         'password' => Hash::make('guest'),
>     ];
> ```

PHP 7.3.33

Laravel Framework 7.19.0

I have also tried using just create and it still takes over a minute

```
$model = static::create($attributes);
```

which create (from the builder class) looks like

```
    /**
     * Save a new model and return the instance.
     *
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|$this
     */
    public function create(array $attributes = [])
    {
        return tap($this->newModelInstance($attributes), function ($instance) {
            $instance->save();
        });
    }
```

for now in the class, I have a function which works and is immediate. I would just like to understand why i can not use the other way

```
public static function createGuestUser(array $attributes = [])
    {
        $newId = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(
            [
                'id' => -1,
                'name' => $attributes['name'],
                'email' => $attributes['email'],
                'phone' => $attributes['phone'],
                'birthday' => $attributes['birthday'],
                'my_role' => 3,
                'password' => $attributes['password']
            ]
        );
        return  self::find($newId);;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Is that your `create` attempt, or the existing code? ... Anyway need more info appended to the question: What is your definition of `a really long time`? ... What is in `$attributes`? ... What versions of Laravel/PHP do you have? Other than that, the first binding `[0] =>` appears to be null, is that expected?

Comment: @PaulT.  This is existing code. I have just added the enableQueryLog


"[0] => appears to be null, is that expected? "   to be honest i am not sure what is expected, i have also updated the original question to include your other questions

Comment: This question has a major problem: there is no "create user code".

Comment: I would have expected to see something along the lines of: `User::create($attributes);` instead of `static::query...`, which Eloquent will do assuming the class extends Model (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54727201/7644018)), but it's unknown based on the current code alone.

Comment: @PaulT. User class extends Authenticatable

I am trying to understand why the original author is doing a query() first instead of just create.  I also trying to find exactly static::query() does.  Lots to learn...

Comment: Wouldn't the query log table contain the history of all queries? That would explain the 10680; you might be retrieving the entire history of queries since it was turned on. To see the queries in the current request I recommend the [barryvdh/laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) package. Another thing: where does `static::query()->create()` lead, could you summarize the code in that function?

Comment: @JorisJ1 query log table, I assume that is a mysql thing not a laravel thing?
Also static::query()->create() and static::create() , call a class in Eloquent builder (see update in original question above)

Comment: I was wrong, I tested and `DB::getQueryLog()` will only show the queries from the current request. Therefore the 10680 things being queried is very likely to be the cause of the slowness. I also tested `static::query()->create($attributes);` (in my User model) and it works fine with a single INSERT being generated. My next guess is that something might be changed in the `create()` function (as in a custom one overriding the one in the base Model). Is there a create function in your User model?

Comment: Also, if you can get the [barryvdh/laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) to work, it will show you exactly where in the code a query is being executed.